# Error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point. Visual Studio 2019 project with a css, js, and html file

Tags: javascript, html, css, computer-science

I've basically copied this code exactly but when I try to publish it in Visual Studio 2019 I get this error;
Error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point.

Code I've used: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-web-based-drawing-application-using-canvas--net-14288

Comment: Try it step by step rather than reaching an error at the end which is harder to debug.

Comment: That does not help at all...